# Using LINQ Where result in foreach: hidden if statement, double foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

```
foreach (Person criminal in people.Where(person => person.isCriminal)
{
    // do something
}
```

I have this piece of code and want to know how does it actually work. Is it equivalent to an if statement nested inside the foreach iteration or does it first loop through the list of people and repeats the loop with selected values? I care to know more about this from the perspective of efficiency.

```
foreach (Person criminal in people)
{
    if (criminal.isCriminal)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Where already filter by IsCriminial. So you will have less loop with the where clause

Comment: if you put the entire logic inside if statement then its equivalent

Comment: Yes. It will give you the first criminal person then call your logic, then next criminal person then call your logic etc.

Comment: You should check Where source code if you want to know the details. Basically, it's pretty much the same and you shouldn't worry about performance at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where` uses *deferred* execution.

This means that the filtering does not occur immediately when you call `Where`. Instead, each time you call `GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` on the return value of `Where`, it checks if the next element in the sequence satisfies the condition. If it does not, it skips over this element and checks the next one. When there is an element that satisfies the condition, it stops advancing and you can get the value using `Current`.

Basically, it is like having an if statement inside a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what happens, you must know how `IEnumerables<T>` work (because LINQ to Objects always work on `IEnumerables<T>`. `IEnumerables<T>` return an `IEnumerator<T>` which implements an iterator. This iterator is lazy, i.e. it always only yields one element of the sequence at once. There is no looping done in advance, unless you have an `OrderBy` or another command which requires it.

So if you have ...

```
foreach (string name in source.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Name)) {
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

... this will happen: The foreach-statement requires the first item which is requested from the `Select`, which in turn requires one item from `Where`, which in turn retrieves one item from the source. The first name is printed to the console.

Then the foreach-statement requires the second item which is requested from the `Select`, which in turn requires one item from `Where`, which in turn retrieves one item from the source. The second name is printed to the console.

and so on.

This means that both of your code snipptes are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `people` is.

If `people` is an `IEnumerable` object (like a collection, or the result of a method using `yield`) then the two pieces of code in your question are indeed equivalent.

A naïve `Where` could be implemented as:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  // Error handling left out for simplicity.
  foreach (TSource item in source)
  {
    if (predicate(item))
    {
      yield return item;
    }
  }
}
```

The actual code in `Enumerable` is a bit different to make sure that errors from passing a null `source` or `predicate` happen immediately rather than on the deferred execution, and to optimise for a few cases (e.g. `source.Where(x => x.IsCriminal).Where(x => x.IsOnParole)` is turned into the equivalent of `source.Where(x => x.IsCriminal && x.IsOnParole)` so that there's one fewer step in the chains of iterations), but that's the basic principle.

If however `people` is an `IQueryable` then things are different, and depend on the details of the query provider in question.

The simplest possibility is that the query provider can't do anything special with the `Where` and so it ends up just doing pretty much the above, because that will still work.

But often the query provider **can** do something else. Let's say `people` is a `DbSet<Person>` in Entity Framework assocated with a table in a database called `people`. If you do:

```
foreach(var person in people)
{
  DoSomething(person);
}
```

Then Entity Framework will run SQL similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
```

And then create a `Person` object for each row returned. We could do the same filtering in about to implement `Where` but we can also do better.

If you do:

```
foreach (Person criminal in people.Where(person => person.isCriminal)
{
  DoSomething(person);
}
```

Then Entity Framework will run SQL similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE isCriminal = 1
```

This means that the logic of deciding which elements to return is done in the database before it comes back to .NET. It allows for indices to be used in computing the `WHERE` which can be much more efficient, but even in the worse case of there being no useful indices and the database having to do a full scan it will still mean that those records we don't care about are never reported back from the database and there is no object created for them just to be thrown away again, so the difference in performance can be immense.

> I care to know more about this from the perspective of efficiency

You are hopefully satisfied that there's no double pass as you suggested might happen, and happy to learn that it's even more efficient than the `foreach … if` you suggested when possible.

A bare `foreach` and `if` will still beat `.Where()` against an `IEnumerable` (but not against a database source) as there are a few overheads to `Where` that `foreach` and `if` don't have, but it's to a degree that is only worth caring about in very hot paths. Generally `Where` can be used with reasonable confidence in its efficiency.